# Pagination using php?

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination

I have two pages,
#page 1 code

```
  <?php
include "db.php";
$select_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM categrios");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_query)){
echo "<a href='page2.php?category_id=".$row["Category_id"]."'><b>".$row["category_name"]."</b></a>";
}
?>
```

The above code gives me the `id` & `names` of category,

On click of `category_name` the page will redirect me to the second page with the `id`,

#page 2 Code

```
<?php
include "db.php";
$id = $_GET["category_id"];
if (isset($_GET['page_no']) && $_GET['page_no']!="") {
  $page_no = $_GET['page_no'];
  } else {
    $page_no = 1;
        }
  $total_records_per_page = 15;
    $offset = ($page_no-1) * $total_records_per_page;
  $previous_page = $page_no - 1;
  $next_page = $page_no + 1;
  $adjacents = "2"; 
  $result_count = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) As total_records FROM medicines");
  $total_records = mysqli_fetch_array($result_count);
  $total_records = $total_records['total_records'];
  $total_no_of_pages = ceil($total_records / $total_records_per_page);
  $second_last = $total_no_of_pages - 1;
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `medicines` LIMIT $offset, $total_records_per_page");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

echo = "<h5 class="card-title text-center"><a href=""><b>".$row["category_name"]."</b></a></h5>";
}
?>
<div style='padding: 10px 20px 0px; align-self: center;margin-left: 45.5em;position: fixed;bottom: 100px;'>
<strong>Page <?php echo $page_no." of ".$total_no_of_pages; ?></strong>

  <ul class="pagination" style="margin-left: 43em;position: fixed;bottom: 30px;">
  <li <?php if($page_no <= 1){ echo "class='disabled'"; } ?>>
  <a <?php if($page_no > 1){ echo "href='?page_no=$previous_page'"; } ?>>Previous</a>
  </li>
       
    <?php 
  if ($total_no_of_pages <= 10){     
    for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $total_no_of_pages; $counter++){
      if ($counter == $page_no) {
       echo "<li class='active'><a>$counter</a></li>";  
        }else{
           echo "<li><a href='?page_no=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
        }
        }
  }
  elseif($total_no_of_pages > 10){
    
  if($page_no <= 4) {     
   for ($counter = 1; $counter < 8; $counter++){     
      if ($counter == $page_no) {
       echo "<li class='active'><a>$counter</a></li>";  
        }else{
           echo "<li><a href='?page_no=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
        }
        }
    echo "<li><a>...</a></li>";
    echo "<li><a href='?page_no=$second_last'>$second_last</a></li>";
    echo "<li><a href='?page_no=$total_no_of_pages'>$total_no_of_pages</a></li>";
    }

   elseif($page_no > 4 && $page_no < $total_no_of_pages - 4) {     
    echo "<li><a href='?page_no=1'>1</a></li>";
    echo "<li><a href='?page_no=2'>2</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a>...</a></li>";
        for ($counter = $page_no - $adjacents; $counter <= $page_no + $adjacents; $counter++) {     
           if ($counter == $page_no) {
       echo "<li class='active'><a>$counter</a></li>";  
        }else{
           echo "<li><a href='?page_no=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
        }                  
       }
       echo "<li><a>...</a></li>";
     echo "<li><a href='?page_no=$second_last'>$second_last</a></li>";
     echo "<li><a href='?page_no=$total_no_of_pages'>$total_no_of_pages</a></li>";      
            }
    
    else {
        echo "<li><a href='?page_no=1'>1</a></li>";
    echo "<li><a href='?page_no=2'>2</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a>...</a></li>";

        for ($counter = $total_no_of_pages - 6; $counter <= $total_no_of_pages; $counter++) {
          if ($counter == $page_no) {
       echo "<li class='active'><a>$counter</a></li>";  
        }else{
           echo "<li><a href='?page_no=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
        }                   
                }
            }
  }
?>
    
  <li <?php if($page_no >= $total_no_of_pages){ echo "class='disabled'"; } ?>>
  <a <?php if($page_no < $total_no_of_pages) { echo "href='?page_no=$next_page'"; } ?>>Next</a>
  </li>
    <?php if($page_no < $total_no_of_pages){
    echo "<li><a href='?page_no=$total_no_of_pages'>Last &rsaquo;&rsaquo;</a></li>";
    } ?>
</ul>
</div>
?>
```

Above is the code which I have tried for pagination,

The problem I am facing is my pagination is not working with where condition,

When page2 loads it gets URL like

> localhost/hindi/page2.php?category_id=2,

And display pagination rows below,

But when I click on next it show URL like

> localhost/hindi/page2.php?page=2

And no data shows

Comment: `<a href='page2.php?category_id=".$row["Category_id"].">` - You're missing the closing `'` for the `href`-attribute.

Comment: but still its not working as i want

Comment: First of all use strings escaping for MySQL to avoid SQL Injections Secondly, i don't see `?category_id=` parameter in page 2?? You should get `?category_id=2&page=3`.

Comment: Below `include` I am getting this parameter `$id = $_GET["category_id"];`@FarZanTakhsha

Comment: Your best bet is to save the query parameters if they are present (or even the query itself) in a session variable, otherwise fetch the query from the session variable; then add LIMIT paging (if you don't have page parameters set to first page).